# How to override attribute setter in Ember Data 1.0.0?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

is there a way to override an attribute setter in Ember Data 1.0.0? I would like to clean up data before any events are fired or computed properties updated.

At now I use the following method, but I don't like it, since I have to always remember to use `dirtyPosition` when setting a new value:

```
SampleApp.Line = DS.Model.extend({

  position: DS.attr("number"),

  dirtyPosition: function(key, value) {
    this.set("position", Math.max(0, value));
  }

});
```

It would be much nicer if I could somehow override the `position` property... But I can't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would try overriding `Ember.Object#set`; Source is [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.4.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/observable.js#L142).